# What is a fast and efficient way to convert a large dictionary of data into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

We have an internalized data that comes in as a dictionary of lists. All of the lists are of the same size.

The data can vary in types and usually are floats, long and short strings, small and large ints, some bits, some booleans etc. This data comes in from a variety of sub-systems. Data sizes vary.

The traditional pd.DataFrame.from_dict is horrendously slow if the data size is large. I have an 18M * 100 data set right now as an example and it takes 15+ minutes when using from_dict.

I tried something like this :

```
ptable = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in tbl_dict.items()}, axis=1)
```

And it provided better timings of 7 minutes. Just throwing it out there to see if anyone has something better.

UPDATE to help visualize the example :
I can't get actual data to be published here. But here is a snippet of some mocked information.

Shape : 18M rows * 100 columns

```
{'ID1' : ['8abcdefgi','9abcdefgi', '1abcdefgi'....],
 'ID2' : [11111,12345,10001, ....],
 'ID3' : [123456789012, 123456789015, 323450789012, ...],
 'ID4' : [553456483415, 444879893478, 893012334091, ...],
 'ID5' : [1233445845, 7843212314, 3843312344, ...],
 'Status' : ['Live', 'Not Live', 'Live'...],
 'Sector' : ['Finance', 'Finance', 'Finance'...], 
 'Name1' : ['Tdjolkajdshytjsbggh-klhn', 'Adgtlkajdyxykgsbgddg-utyj'...],
 'Name2' : ['Equities Desk', None, 'Equities Desk', 'Commodities Desk'...]
 'ID6' : [76534, 90654, 78456...],
 'Name3' : ['ABC', 'BCD', None...],
 'Type1' : [None, None, None...],
 'Flag1' : [0,0,1,0,...],
 'Flag2' : ['true', 'false', 'true', 'true'...],
 'ID7' : [123456789, 873631826, 876391723, 316071258...],
 'Type2' : ['ABC', 'DDD', 'AHY',...], 
 'Name4' : ['Desk Name', 'Desk Name', 'Desk Name'...], 
 ... }
```

After 'Name4', the remaining 63 columns are either like 'Flag2' or 'Type1'. I would say 80% of the remaining population are like 'Flag2'

Update :
I tried the following and it produced much better timings between 5 to 6 minutes. I also increased the number of columns to 100 ( the original data had 60 columns)

```
temp = pd.DataFrame()
i = 0
s = pd.Series(tbl_dict) # this is actually instant
cols = list(s.index)

# the below simply appends vertically the data into a proper table
while True and i < len(cols) :
  c = cols[i]
  temp[c] = s[i]
  i+=1
```

Comment: what's the result **supposed to look like**?

Comment: I assume that you want to fill columns with fewer rows with None, as your code does. Can you tell me how many columns have fewer rows? I mean, how many of the 60 columns do not contain None?

Comment: One more thing, even if your table is huge, 7 minutes is too slow. Maybe not enough memory?

Comment: @ken : All of the columns have exact number of rows. Nothing to fill out. I work in a proprietary environment and we do apply distributed computing. Memory is not a limiting factor. I would say 60-70% of the columns in this example do not contain None. You got me thinking though : should I anticipate what I am going to load up? Is there some preprocessing I need to asses? Are Nones loading into a dict gonna cause slowness?

Comment: Your very first example has a different number of rows. I think most readers misunderstood your question because of that. But now I am curious about the performance difference between the `from_dict` and `concat`. For normalized data, more than double is definitely something wrong. I tested both with a randomly generated 18M x 60 table based on your description and found the difference to be 20-30% at most. I bet this problem is not just because the table is too big. You may want to narrow down the cause of your noticeable difference by deleting columns and rows from the table.

Comment: By the way, You might want to try `t = pd.DataFrame(tbl_dict, dtype=object); t.infer_objects(copy=False)`, which is more efficient for large lists containing a lot of None. However, it may be useless until you fix the slow `from_dict` problem above.

Comment: @ken : Thank you.  I removed my first statement.  I have a strong suspicion it's Nones. Will do some more experiments.

Comment: `while True and i < len(cols)` ? I don't get this. It looks like you meant to write a for loop. But while True is expected to give you other problems than performance.

Comment: In our environment, it actually doesn't! One strange observation : without the while True, it actually takes a minute longer. I will try again with a few more loops. Just haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: I have no idea how *while true and condition* could accelerate a *while condition* loop. Best I leave the matter to other people. I stick to Ken's and my suggestions,backed by data from my PC.

Comment: You may post your own solution if that worked better for you. It might be of interest to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Provided all values have the same length in your dictionary, there really is no need to recreate it via comprehension. Simply insert your dictionary into `pd.DataFrame()`.

Comparing execution times:

- `ptable = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in tbl_dict.items()}, axis=1)`:

  0.009 +/- 0.003 (blue(ish)
- `ptable = pd.DataFrame(tbl_dict)`:

  0.002 +/- 0.003 (pink(ish))

[image: histogramm of execution times]

Data was obtained on a laptop using this dictionary, where every values are of same length:

```py
tbl_dict
{'ID1': {0: '8abcdefgi', 1: '9abcdefgi', 2: '1abcdefgi', 3: nan},
 'ID2': {0: 11111.0, 1: 12345.0, 2: 10001.0, 3: nan},
 'ID3': {0: 123456789012.0, 1: 123456789015.0, 2: 323450789012.0, 3: nan},
 'ID4': {0: 553456483415.0, 1: 444879893478.0, 2: 893012334091.0, 3: nan},
 'ID5': {0: 1233445845.0, 1: 7843212314.0, 2: 3843312344.0, 3: nan},
 'Status': {0: 'Live', 1: 'Not Live', 2: 'Live', 3: nan},
 'Sector': {0: 'Finance', 1: 'Finance', 2: 'Finance', 3: nan},
 'Name1': {0: 'Tdjolkajdshytjsbggh-klhn',
  1: 'Adgtlkajdyxykgsbgddg-utyj',
  2: nan,
  3: nan},
 'Name2': {0: 'Equities Desk',
  1: None,
  2: 'Equities Desk',
  3: 'Commodities Desk'},
 'ID6': {0: 76534.0, 1: 90654.0, 2: 78456.0, 3: nan},
 'Name3': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'BCD', 2: None, 3: nan},
 'Type1': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: nan},
 'Flag1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0},
 'Flag2': {0: 'true', 1: 'false', 2: 'true', 3: 'true'},
 'ID7': {0: 123456789, 1: 873631826, 2: 876391723, 3: 316071258},
 'Type2': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'DDD', 2: 'AHY', 3: nan},
 'Name4': {0: 'Desk Name', 1: 'Desk Name', 2: 'Desk Name', 3: nan}}
```

Comment: Thanks @OCa. I have something more roundabout that actually improved by 2 minutes. I might be going loony, but here is what I did :

1. After I got the dictionary, I converted it to a Series object. pd.Series(tbl_dict). The keys will be indexed.                                                                                                                                           

2. I created an empty datadframe

3. Did a while loop, to loop through the series object and append the values into the empty dataframe.

Instead of 7 minutes, it takes 5 minutes for 18M rows * 63 columns!

Comment: nice, maybe, however I don't understand why you just wouldn't even try `pd.DataFrame(tbl_dict)` ? Or have you?

Comment: I did, and it still took 7 minutes. Let me update my post with my findings.

Comment: i updated to what I did. I am pretty sure even that can be optimized to a one liner.